# CSS: Div Wrapping Image

Tags: html, css

I have an img element with  `style='width:40%;height:40%;'`. I would like to add a div that automatically wraps it. However when I insert the div instead of wrapping the img it just expands to the div inside.

How can I force this div to wrap img so it can be used as a frame. The reason why I do not preset the div's height and width is because img's percentages will be given dynamically, so div should wrap the img according to img's sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with a width and height of 40% with an image tag, is that the image isn't downscaled to 40% of it's original size, but takes up 40% of it's parent, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MY7wG/).

In your case, you want to wrap the image in a div, but still want to size it to 40% of it's parent. In this case, the parent IS the wrapping div. You see the problem.

If you just want to use the div as a frame, you can use css to style the image to gain a similar effect, like this:

```
<img src="..." style="border: 1px solid #000000; padding:10px;"/>​
```

Example of this principle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cz6C9/2/).

Answer (score 4):

If you do it like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

you could add the **`display: inline-block;`** attribute to the `wrapper`. That did it for me. Yet still, your `style='width:40%;height:40%;'` will make its height being adjusted by its parent as @jesse-van-assen already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

make all your images float to left.

```
img
{
 float:left;
}
```

and clear each div with

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

as the very last element in the wrap div before it closes.

hope it helps.